# Get a word in a file

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program that searches if a word is in the file and then prints it.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("test.cfg", "rt");

if (fp)
{
    char szFileName[256];
    char country[4 + 1];
    char line[256];

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line) - 1, fp)) {
        sprintf(country);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

What's wrong? Sorry for a newbie question.

Comment: In what way is your program failing to meet expectations?

Comment: Not enough arguments to `sprintf`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid test made. code edited

Comment: `szFileName` is unused.

Comment: What's the point of subtracting 1 from `sizeof(line)` in `fgets`?

Comment: `"rt"` is not a standard `fopen` mode.

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++? Your code looks like C but you tagged C++.

Comment: C++ | Im just a newbie in C++, sorry

Comment: `country` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues in your program (uninitialized variables, wrong number of arguments to `sprintf`), and it does not even reflect what you actually want (searching for a word, for example).

In C++, you might use streams instead of the `FILE`-approach. Thereby you can make use of dynamic data structures like `std::string` that prevents you from having to know the maximum line size in advance. See the following code, which shows that the task is rather easy:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream is("somefile.txt");
    if (is.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(is, line)) {
            if (line.find("wordtosearchfor") != std::string::npos) {
                std::cout << line << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "could not open file." << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program looks like a C program. So here's one way to look for a string, say `country`, in the input file and print whether the string exists in the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* fp = fopen("test.cfg", "r");
  if (fp) {
    char country[] = "canada";
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
      if (strstr(line, country) != NULL) {
        printf("String '%s' is present in file\n", country);
        break;
      }
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In this code example, if `test.cfg` contains the string stored in `country`, then the code prints a string indicating this and breaks out of the while loop. If the string does not exist in the file, nothing is printed.

Note: As others have pointed out, `rt` is not a standard `fopen` mode. Also, if you are indeed planning on searching `country` in the file, then you need to initialize it first before using it.